# Joomla menu assignment not working for search page

Tags: search, joomla, content-management-system

I have a few modules assigned only for Home page but by some reason they all showing on search page. I don't need any modules showing on search page - how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to make a menu item for the search page. Without a  menu item, many pages will revert to the homepage link as the active menu item, which will cause this to happen.

If you haven't already, make a hidden menu for your site and then add the menu item for the search results page to that menu. This way it doesn't affect your main menu.

So first go Menus -> Menu Manager -> Add New Menu. Give it a name basically. (I usually call mine "Hidden".) Then go into that menu and add a menu item like normal for the Search Result type.

Comment: Additionally you might have to specify the Itemid of this new menu item in the mod_search module so the page is actually used.